# How do I query this case

Tags: sql, postgresql

DB: PostgreSQL

Suppose I have

```
table A(integer a_id, timestamp x, timestamp y) 
table B(int b_id, timestamp n, timestamp m)
```

`m` can be `null`

I want to fetch the data with this structure

```
SELECT a_id, j.b_id, k.b_id 
FROM A, B AS j, B AS k 
WHERE (x BETWEEN j.n AND j.m) AND (y BETWEEN k.n AND k.m.)
```

When `(x BETWEEN j.n AND j.m) AND (y BETWEEN k.n AND k.m.)`'s matches aren't not found

I still want the query to fetch the data with `null j.b_id` or `null k.b_id`

How do I do that?

Comment: "aren't not found"? So when they are found?

Comment: Please clarify your ambiguous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation of the cryptic question ...

```
SELECT a_id, j.b_id, k.b_id 
FROM   a
LEFT   JOIN b j ON a.x BETWEEN j.n AND j.m
LEFT   JOIN b k ON a.y BETWEEN k.n AND k.m
```

If no matching row is found in `j` or `k`, `NULL` is delivered for `j.b_id` or `k.b_id` respectively.

The query suffers from the principal design flaw that multiple matches in `b` will multiply the number of rows returned in a `CROSS JOIN` fashion.

Comment: Sorry :( I'm not too good at explaining things haha. But hey, I knew someone's gonna figure out what I meant. And you did! Your solution works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use an outer join and factor in NULLs:

```
SELECT a_id, j.b_id, k.b_id 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B AS j ON x >= j.n AND (x <= j.m OR j.m IS NULL)
LEFT JOIN B AS k ON y >= k.n AND (y <= k.m OR k.m IS NULL)
```